# GooglePlayGameServicesを使ったiOSアプリでユーザー認証をするとクラッシュする

Tags: ios, xcode, unity3d, google-play-service

UnityでビルドしたiOSアプリ内でGPGのユーザー認証を行うとクラッシュしてしまいます。
iOSでもクラッシュせずに認証する方法はありますか？

Xcodeのスレッド表示

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
0x32390df4:  mov    r12, #0x148
0x32390df8:  svc    #0x80
0x32390dfc:  blo    0x32390e14                ; __pthread_kill + 32
0x32390e00:  ldr    r12, [pc, #4]             ; __pthread_kill + 24
0x32390e04:  ldr    r12, [pc, r12]
0x32390e08:  b      0x32390e10                ; __pthread_kill + 28
0x32390e0c:  subeq  r4, r8, #0x80000001
0x32390e10:  bx     r12
0x32390e14:  bx     lr
```

使用バージョン

```
Unity 3D 4.6.3f1
  Google Play Games Plugin for Unity v0.9.11

Xcode 6.1.1
  GooglePlayGames SDK v3.1.1
  GoogleMobileAds SDK v7.0.0
  Google Plus SDK v1.7.1
  Google Play Games C++ SDK v1.3
```

なお、Androidでは問題なく認証しており、リーダーボード使用や実績解除も行うことが出来ております。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しましたので、簡単ですが解決方法を記載いたします。

- GooglePlayGames.framework を削除（GooglePlayGames.bundleは削除しない）
- [Build Setting] → [Other Linker Flag] に -ObjC を追加
- [Build Setting] → [Apple LLVM 6.0 - Language - Modules] Enable Modules (C and Objective-C) PROJECT/TARGETSの両方をYesに変更
- [Info] → [URL Types] 何もなければ + をクリックして追加。"Identifier"と"URL Schemes"にはGoogleDeveloperConsoleのリンク済みアプリにあるBundle IDを入れる。両方とも同じもので良い。

これらの作業を終えてからビルドが通りました。